# Uploading file to Azure blob storage in server

Tags: javascript, azure-blob-storage, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I already have a SasBlobUrl(Created by C#). How to upload file using js and my sasUrl. Could i create a blockBlobClient from sasUrl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could i create a blockBlobClient from sasUrl?

Yes, you can. You will use [`BlockBlobClient(string, PipelineLike)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blockblobclient-constructor-2) constructor to create a new instance of `BlockBlobClient` by passing the SAS URL as the first parameter.

From the same link:

> A URL string pointing to Azure Storage block blob, such as
> "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/blockblob". **You
> can append a SAS if using AnonymousCredential, such as
> "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/blockblob?sasString"**.